# Using express sessions in APIs

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am trying to figure out how express-session can be used in an API which could be used on any website. For example, I wrote a small server for this question. The server increments count in the user's session and logs it to the console. The current problem with this is that this does not work if a user calls it from a different domain. It will always output "1" since the session is never saved. If this was done on localhost it would save and increment each time it is called.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'abc',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.post("/exampleapi",(req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    if(!req.session.count) req.session.count = 0;
    
    req.session.count += 1
    
    console.log(req.session.count);
    res.sendStatus(200)
})

http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server.js ready');
});
```

The output I was expecting was that the session data count gets saved for that domain (or all domains) so it gets incremented each call. Currently the api only works on localhost. I have a feeling that this is not possible. If it's not possible, what's the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Express-session is tied to a specific cookie so if the endpoint comes from a difference device, it will not have that cookie any more and you cannot change that.  You can implement a login where you create a new cookie on the new device and then tied that new cookie to a particular user's data.  To do that, the API would have to first login and then would have to preserve and resend the cookie when they next use the API as that user.  For plain APIs without cookies, you would typically use something like a custom header with authentication or token in it that would also come from login.

Comment: I hope you understand that your server can't just magically know what user (and what corresponding session data goes with that user) is on the other end of a request without some sort of identifying information sent with the request.  Express-session uses a cookie to identify the user, but that cookie is only good for that specific device (since only that device has the cookie).